# jQuery: dom insertion selector problem after .get

Tags: jquery, dom, get, css-selectors, insertion

HI Volks,

here is my code block which I want to replace by the ajax respond:

```
<div class="results">
  <span id="like9">
    <a class="like" rel="ajax.php?id=9" href="#">klick</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

this is how I observe the ajax link:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.results .like').click(function()
  {
     params = getUrlVars($(this).attr('rel'));
     $.get($(this).attr('rel'), function(data)
     {
       $('#like'+params['id']).html(data); 
     });

     return false;
  });
});
```

After I click on the link, everythings works fine, and the code block will be replace how expected. Everthing is equal except the link name.

But when I click a second time on the link, the selector does not work any more.
I think because the old a.like was replaced.

My question is, **how can I tell jquery or the DOM that there is a new DOM node**?

I'm hoping for help. THX a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to use jQuery.live()

```
$(selector).live("click", function() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$('.clickme').click()` which is a one-time `bind()`, try `$('.clickme').live('click', function() { ... });` which essentially monitors for changes and maintains the bind across DOM changes.

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for more.

Comment: Thx for the more detailed answer :-)